# How to specify maven bin in eclipse maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I have eclipse with maven plugin coming with it on CentOs. How can I execute maven command on linx like:

mvn clean package

```
[abigail@localhost ~]$ mvn
bash: mvn: command not found
```

How should I specify the path to the executable of maven plugin in eclipse? Or I have to install maven seperately？ Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse (M2E) have bundled the central parts of maven inside an eclipse plugin, which is why it is not easily detected, and not really that usable. You could probably by investigation find the correct way to bootstrap it, but you will have to create the launcher file manually.

If you want to run maven outside of eclipse, you are far better off with a standalone version of Maven. Then you will get the `mvn` command to bootstrap the maven runtime system correctly, and secondly, you will be able to use all the advice concerning the use of Maven. The maven binaries are quite stable, so you wouldn't need to upgrade it as often as you upgrade Eclipse.

You can subsequently switch eclipse to use your external installation if you so prefer.

Answer (score 0):

set `PATH` variable to include `mvn`

```
export PATH=/path/to/apcha-maven-directory/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: I am asking where is "apcha-maven-directory" located in eclipse maven. I don't want to install maven again, since it's already part of eclipse as a plugin.

Comment: don't stay dependent on eclipse plugin's maven, download standalone maven from apache and include it

Comment: In this case, it's better to use the same version of maven in eclipse, because I primarily develop in eclipse, where maven is used. Separate installation is one choice, but duplicated.

Comment: That's why I install a separate (up-to-date) installation of Maven and make Eclipse use that rather than the embedded one. Using outdated embedded installations is one choice, but not the best one.